# C: modify array specifec charin c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, scanf

in this C code
why I can't change the value of element a[0] and I just can enter it one time?
and what should I do if I want to change the value of the element a[0]?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
char a[20];
char* p;

void klam(void) {
p = a;
scanf("%c", &p[0]);
scanf("%c", &p[0]);
 }
 int main() {

 klam();
 printf("%c", a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the function

```
void klam(void) {
p = a;
scanf("%c", &p[0]);
scanf("%c", &p[0]);
 }
```

the element `p[0]` is modified twice. It seems that in the second call it is set by the new line character `'\n'` that is placed in the input buffer after pressing the Enter key.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c;
    
    scanf( "%c", &c );
    printf( "The code of the character c is %d\n", c );

    scanf( "%c", &c );
    printf( "The code of the character c is %d\n", c );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the character `A` and then to press the Enter key then the program output will be

```
The code of the character c is 65
The code of the character c is 10
```

where `65` is the ASCII code of the letter `A` and `10` is the code of the new line character `'\n'`.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
void klam(void) {
p = a;
scanf(" %c", &p[0]);
 }
```

or like

```
void klam(void) {
p = a;
scanf(" %c", &p[0]);
scanf(" %c", &p[0]);
 }
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c` within the call of the function `scanf`. It allows to skip white spaces.